# why does my logger not inherit handlers from root logger

Tags: python, django, logging

I have followed advice from django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#examples) and other SO questions about how to configure logs in a django project.

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d [%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

portfolio/models.py:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def testfunc():
    print(logger)
    print(logger.handlers)
```

when i run `testfunc` i get the following output:

```
>>> testfunc()
<Logger portfolio.models (INFO)>
[]
```

however if i add a logger explicitly to my config like so:

```
'root': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'INFO',
},
'loggers': {
    'portfolio.models': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

then the handler is picked up by the logger:

```
>>> testfunc()
<Logger portfolio.models (INFO)>
[<StreamHandler <stderr> (INFO)>]
```

I have also tried creating a 'catch-all' logger like based on another SO answer:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

but this didn't work.

Any ideas why i can't get my logger to inherit from the root logger?

EDIT i can no show that `level` is being inherited from the root logger, but for whatever reason handlers are not still being inherited

Comment: Seems like you don't have a logger named ***`portfolio.models`***

Comment: I thought by creating root logger in settings.py that i could instantiate my loggers in each model using `logging.getLogger(__name__)` and they will inherit from the root logger https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#examples

Comment: I have this in [my settings](https://pastebin.com/mx2jSz73) and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Loggers don't actually "inherit" the root loggers handlers. They propagate logs to the roots handlers. So functionally it is as if those handlers where also attached to your logger, but if you want to see them you have to check directly at the root logger. You could see the effect of this if you would put something like `logger.warning('also handled by root handlers')` into your `testfunc()`.